# reuse cell in three20

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, three20

In my `- (void)setObject:(id)object` method, sometimes I am adding a 0..10 UIImageView dynamically to the cell depending on the object. Now the issue is how do I remove these UIImageView from the cell in my prepareForReuse?

I have tried doing it via a stupid way, which is to tag each UIImageView from -1 to -10, then in my prepareForReuse I check if it exists, if it does I remove it and then check for the next one. Is there any easier method than this?

Answer (score 0):

You should make each cell contain spots for every imageview you want to display in its own subclass. When you implement `prepareForReuse` in your subclass, set them all to hidden, and in your `setObject` call, determine which ones need to be unhidden.

Comment: the issue is that I don't know in advance how many imageview I will have, the number is random.. I know I said in my post it's 0..10, but it can be more than 10, as this is pulling the data from the API so I never knew how much to expect

Comment: perhaps if you can clarify what you mean by "every imageview you want to display in its own subclass", it would make more sense for me

Comment: The image views are contained in the cell's subclass. You only have two options here: 1) Create the imageViews as needed on scroll (SLOW) or pre-create the imageViews in the cell and only show/hide them on scroll (FAST, USES MORE MEMORY). I would instead look for a design change as 10+ images items in a single cell is bad UI

Comment: what about creating the image in setObject? Is that what you mean in the second option? and when you mean pre-create the imageViews, you mean creating the TTImageView right?

Comment: Creating the images in setObject is the first option. You should not do much login during a scroll or you will see decreased performance when on a real device. Yes for your second question.

Comment: if I were to go with the first option, how would I remove it for cell reuse? issue with pre-creating them and hide them when not used, is I don't know how many to allocate, I can allocate 10 and hope that it won't have more than 10 image in a cell.. but making such assumption just doesn't feel right

Comment: If you were to do it that way, yes you would set the hidden attribute to YES on the call, but I would highly suggest a different UI option for this, perhaps just a single button that when pressed shows all other icons.

Comment: so if there are only 2-3 images lets say/assume, which path would you go with? giving a brief overview, the majority of the cell here doesn't have this image.. the probability is possible 1:50, so 1 cell out of 50 that has an image. So doing the pre-creation is rather useless. Now I am talking about the other method which you mentioned is slow. How do I remove the image from this cell for reuse?

Comment: @coneybeare let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1806/discussion-between-adit-and-coneybeare)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
- (void)prepareForReuse {
    [super prepareForReuse];
    [_photoImage unsetImage];   
}
```